# Python access to cycles' transparent film

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

There used to be a variable `bpy.context.scene.cycles.film_transparent`,
Not anymore but i'm working with an old script and need to retrieve the equivalent.
There are:
`bpy.context.scene.cycles.film_transparent_glass`
`bpy.context.scene.cycles.film_transparent_roughness`
But I need the checkbox "Transparent" variable's which appears under the film layout in cycles' render options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of Blender this property is part of scene data, you can access it with `bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent`

Comment: Make sure to mark your post as the solution to notify others that this thread's question has already been solved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) or short description of what the  code does. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.